# Enable SSO for Excel Addin With Manual steps by not using npm run configure-sso command

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

With using the configure cmd new azure app will create and this is not permissable everywhere. We already have an az AD clientid Can anyone provide steps for implementing sso manually without dependency with credentials store.

Help is highly appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The official documentation has a lot about this. Have you seen this: [Register SSO Add-in in AAD V.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2).